# Migration to JBOSS 7

Tags: jsf-2, jboss7.x, mojarra

I have migrated application from Spring 3.0.5, JBOSS 5, hibernate 3 to Spring 3.2.3, JBOSS 7 , hibernate 4. I am able to build and finally open the UI ( JSF ) also. But on UI Dropdown selects and popups etc are not working.
On selection a value from select box, it gives error "Uncaught ReferenceError: mojarra is not defined "

The same migrated setup, I have deployed on Tomcat instead of JBOSS7. It is completely working fine.

Please suggest if I am missing anything or anything extra jars required to deploy on JBOSS 7 than Tomcat 7

Comment: The error is about mojarra-JSF, but you don't specify the version which you come from and the exact version of Mojarra you're migrating to. JBoss provides its own Mojarra implementation, so you need to check the versions which you come from/go to that are actually the root cause of the problem.

Comment: Earlier we were using Mojarra 2.1.2 and JBOSS7 now using Mojarra 2.1.7